# Error when creating a Meteor project

Tags: meteor

I have several Meteor-based apps that work fine.

However, today, I wanted to create a new project (with meteor create project-name), but I get the following error:

```
/Users/{me}/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.1_1.1sugdc6++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:165
      throw error;
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/private/var/folders/wt/j0lmggts0zx4h0wkdsywg5800000gn/T/mt-iwcg4k/plugin.compileTemplatesBatch.os/program.json'
    at Error (native)
```

What is causing this? How to solve this?

If it makes a difference, I'm on OSX 10.11.6

Comment: I'm using Blaze and did not have to explicitly rebuild npm.

Comment: Same solution will work.I was also using blaze. The issue arises due to version bump of node in meteor 1.4 onwards.